# Netbeans + Scala + play-framework : index.html isn't found

Tags: scala, netbeans, playframework

I've just netbeansified a plain play project with scala. Netbeans has no problems with opening or editing the project but if I try to run it this happens:

> > @68095ke10 Application.index action not found
>
> Action not found Action Application.index could not be found. Error
>   raised is Controller controllers.Application not found
>
> play.exceptions.ActionNotFoundException: Action Application.index not
>   found     at
>   play.mvc.ActionInvoker.getActionMethod(ActionInvoker.java:588)    at
>   play.mvc.ActionInvoker.resolve(ActionInvoker.java:85)     at
>   Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!) Caused by: java.lang.Exception:
>   Controller controllers.Application not found  ... 3 more

First I tried to rename and restructure the project so that index.html would be found. Yet I soon realized that this was no help at all. After undoing my changes I tried to start the app by play run on the console. Somehow this worked. Netbeans is version 7.0.1. Play is version 1.2.3 . Scala was installed by the typesafe-stack. Netbeans plugin is up to date with version 2.9.x. What is wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a path to the scala module lib folder to your project, and when you run the app, see if it says "Scala support is active" you'll notice this happens when running from the console, but not netbeans.